# La structure du subjonctif : existe-t-elle ?

Tags: grammaire

Est-ce qu'une structure cohérente existe sur laquelle sont fondées les règles du subjonctif ?

Si une telle structure existe, cela vaut mieux que l'option qui consiste à apprendre tous les exemples où il faut l'utiliser.

Comment: Quelle sorte de structure? On peut raisonner que l'ensemble des exemples du subjonctif s'en fait une. Il faut aussi rappeller que le subjonctif en français (et dans les autres langues indoeuropéenes) provient originalement du [PIE](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-europ%C3%A9en_commun#Verbes) et donc une telle structure en serait une dégradation (ou une succession de modifications).

Answer (score 1):

Mon **opinion** (déjà évoquée ici en une autre occasion... m'ayant valu les foudres des downvoteurs de tout poil... souffrez que... je me marre ! Mais... c'est un signe : je ne sache pas qu'elle fasse l'unanimité... **ici-là**) : :-)

---

Bref! Le subjonctif... [*J'en pleure des larmes de sang et ces choses amèneront ma mort prématurée. Le plus tragique est... qu'elle n'y changerait rien*...](http://chasseautresor-ng.0707a.net/forum/index.php?topic=63.0) ;-)

Qu'on me permette de faire observer qu'une grammaire contemporaine renommée commence son article sur le subjonctif par un *"Le subjonctif **devrait s**'utiliser..."*
 Vous avez vu ce conditionnel ? sans compter le réfléchi, par surcroît...

On **doit** ? ha bhé... non! On **doit** pas! On **devrait**. Si on veut quoi! Et puis en plus c'est même pas *on*... il **se** mettrait tout seul... :-)

Au XXIè siècle, Le subjonctif est un mode et les modes sont... à la disposition du locuteur ad libitum. Le locuteur l'utilise dans une proposition principale s'il souhaite marquer une nuance dans sa pensée et dans une proposition subordonnée pour nuancer la force du verbe de la principale.

Bon... le locuteur peut aussi vouloir faire genre salon du XIXè et en mettre comme la muscade dans les dîners... c'est pas interdit non plus.

Le plus important à retenir de tout cela c'est ce qu'en dit, et avec raison l'ami Vialatte qui parle le français très mieux que moi :

Le plus important n'est pas de savoir quand il **faut** le mettre puisqu'on le met quand on veut. Le plus important c'est, quand on le met : **De savoir le conjuguer**! Connaître les règles de concordance des temps qui ne répondent qu'à une très simple logique de conséquence.

Pas de souçi pour toi dans cette optique : Ces règles sont et [cohérentes et structurées et, somme toute,... assez... simples!](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/concordance-des-temps.php)

Donc Non! Il n'y a pas de *structure* du subjonctif.
De structuré je ne connais que la pensée qui structure la phrase. Quand la pensée n'est pas structurée, tu peux balancer de l'indicatif que... ça ne le fera pas... non plus!
L'utilisation du subjonctif procède de la structure de la phrase, structure qui se traduit (pour les verbes) par leur position et leurs concordances.

Le mode n'est qu'un outil! *Provide tools not policy* comme on dit en d'autres lieux. Je sais que l'informatique moderne a tendance à vendre des outils structurants (pour pallier les déficiences des utilisateurs) mais... *Thanks God*... cela n'est pas le cas des outils linguistiques.

Eussé-je voulu assister au décompte des rageux, je ne m'y serais pris autrement. N'est-il pas ?
(hé oui! C'est une vraie cata ce truc, il faut aussi apprendre les cas de post-position du sujet...) pffff! ;-)

Comment: Vous faites de votre réponse un exercice en cynisme gratuit?

Answer (score 0):

L'essentiel de la grammaire du subjonctif se trouve [ici](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=subjonctif&btn_chercher=CHERCHER).

Un site du journal « Le Monde » donne [accès à la conjugaison](https://conjugaison.lemonde.fr/conjugaison/) des verbes (tous modes et temps).

Il existe cependant certaines tendances et des problèmes qui font que tout le monde n'est pas d'accord tout le temps sur l'usage du subjonctif.

Il est sans aucun doute important d'apprendre les règles de base, comme elle sont formulées par exemple dans la référence ci-dessus.

ADDITION

La question, dans sa formulation me semblait incohérente, et je ne pensais pas devoir y répondre formellement; ayant perçu que dans son essence elle représente un tâtonnement en plusieurs directions, je me suis laissé allé à suivre son « fil cassé »; le résultat n'est pas une réponse puisque il prouve l'incohérence de la question; il a cependant le mérite en même temps de fournir des éclaircissements dans le domaine « visé largement » par cette question; comme après tout, c'est une question,  bien qu'un chaos en elle-même, qui reste acceptable aux yeux de la communauté FSE, j'ai cru sans mauvaise conséquence d'ajouter l'analyse double que représente le résultat au minimum initial que j'avais proposé.

Le terme « structure » dans la question est un problème, et la question d'existence en est un autre; d'après les termes, on peut percevoir vaguement ce qui est demandé mais il est nécessaire de mettre de l'ordre dans les idées, et donc en même temps qu'une vue d'ensemble de ce qu'est le subjonctif est développée, la question et ses termes sont examinés vis-à-vis des concepts considérés.

**A**  Le subjonctif peut être considéré comme étant un **aspect** des actions et états trouvés dans le texte tels qu'exprimés par les formes verbales, en d'autres termes il peut être vu comme étant une **classification** (classe), spécifiquement celle des actions et états qui peuvent **découler**, en tant que possibilités,  des actions réelles ou des états réels, lesquels sont exprimés au moyen des temps de l'indicatif ; c'est pour cette raison que l'on ne trouve le subjonctif que peu dans une principale et qu'il doit pratiquement toujours dépendre d'une principale ou autre proposition (une subordonnée) présentant l'action ou l'état réel qui implique une action ou état non réalisé. Cette nature du subjonctif se lit dans son étymologie : **sub** (*en dessous*, donc « sous la principale, le réel ») et **jungere** (*ajouter* ) et on a l'idée d'un concept ajouté et soumis à la principale (ou une subordonnée). Il y a des cas peu courants dans lesquelles le subjonctif ne se trouve pas dans une subordonnée mais ce sont des cas de constructions spéciales; on remarque que beaucoup de ces phrases  sont des phrases exclamatives. Par exemple, des trois phrases suivantes deux sont des indépendantes avec le verbe au présent du subjonctif et la dernière a une principale avec le verbe aussi au présent du subjonctif.

- Que le ciel nous vienne en aide!
- Advienne que pourra!
- Dieu fasse que cela tourne bien.

Les verbes dans les principales introduisant le subjonctif  sont soit des verbes qui expriment souvent un état d'esprit (**(a)** ci-dessous) et ils sont alors souvent suivis par la conjonction « que », mais pas toujours, ou bien ce sont des verbes d'action ou d'état d'esprit (**(b)** ci-dessous) et ils sont suivis par des **locutions conjonctives** qui appellent le subjonctif ; elles appellent le subjonctif parce que l'action ou état qu'elles impliquent, de par leur sens, ne peut pas être réel ; il existe cependant des cas de locution qui font partiellement exception à la règle.

- **(a)** douter, craindre, avoir peur, souhaiter, vouloir, désirer, exiger, détester, regretter, supposer, assumer, comprendre,…  (*n'exprime pas un état d'esprit*) : falloir ,  être nécessaire, sembler
- **(b)**  en sorte que, de sorte que, pour que, afin que, sans que, (*il existe un grand nombre de ces locutions*)

<sub>Note _ Les règles sont cependant respectées selon des degrés variés propres à chaque verbe; par exemple, pour « croire » et « penser » la règle n'est pratiquement pas respectée.</sub>

Le principe de stricte dépendance du choix du mode subjonctif sur le verbe de la principale  et seulement sur la principale n'est pas exact dans les détails; il l'est seulement dans l'ensemble; des exemples illustrant ce point sont maintenant donnés, cela dans le but de cerner plus exactement la nature de ce qu'est le subjonctif; la nécessité du subjonctif après le verbe de la principale ne dépend pas nécessairement que du verbe et peut dépendre à la fois du verbe et d'un complément circonstanciel du verbe de la subordonnée. Par exemple, avec " falloir " on n'a pas le choix : il est absolument nécessaire d'utiliser le subjonctif (<s>Il faut qu'il vient.</s>).

> Il comprend qu'il y **a** peu de monde intéressé.
>   - (*Il y a peu de monde intéressé, cela depuis un certain temps jusqu'au moment de l'énonciation et cet état de chose devrait continuer dans le futur.*)
>
> Il comprend qu'il y **ait**  peu de monde intéressé lorsque **c'est l'hiver/ en hiver**.
>   - (*Au moment où l'énonciation est faite il peut y avoir ou ne pas y avoir peu de monde intéressé, l'état avancé n'est pas nécessairement vérifiable au présent*)

Si selon les bases abordées ci-dessus on veut parler  de l'ensemble des constructions de phrase avec le subjonctif dans une subordonnée en tant que structure du subjonctif, comme on place le subjonctif sur un pied d'égalité avec l'indicatif (les deux sont des modes employés dans les subordonnées), la même définition doit être faite pour l'indicatif; cela semble sans problème. Ces structures ne s'arrête pas à la subordonnée puisque l'on **considère qu'il existe une structure en vertu de la construction « principale-subordonnée » réalisé par un lien** (conjonction, locution conjonctive, pronom) ; elle englobe la principale ; on doit sous-entendre donc « la structure (de l'indicatif/du subjonctif) en subordonnée ». C'est le contexte essentiel d'utilisation du subjonctif. Il est possible de parler de la **structure du subjonctif ou de l'indicatif** selon cette idée mais en grammaire il semble que l'on n'utilise que le terme « **construction** »; on peut dire par exemple « construction avec le subjonctif ».

Demander selon ce point de vue de définition de « structure du subjonctif » si cette structure existe ne correspond pas vraiment à une question que poserait un étudiant du langage ; tout d'abord, douter qu'une structure existe implique une connaissance de plusieurs idées de base, dont celle de l'existence de formes verbales spéciales, donc d'une construction. Il semble qu'il faille écarter comme irréaliste cette façon de comprendre la question. Le corps de la question tend à confirmer que cela est justifié.

**B** On lit dans ce qui développe l'idée de la question contenue dans le titre, qu'il ne peut pas s'agir de la structure en tant que ce qui vient d'être considéré mais de la première de deux choses; la première est le concept justificatif dans l'emploi du subjonctif et la seconde est tout cela qui constitue ce qui a été appelé « *les règles* », c'est à dire la question de où employer le subjonctif puis celle de la concordance des temps. Le concept justificatif pourrait aussi être appelé la nature fondamentale du subjonctif. Il ne s'agit pas d'une structure mais d'une relation, cette relation étant grosso modo « représenter une action ou un état du monde réel qui est seulement une possibilité non matérialisée ». Cette relation existe parce que l'on peut faire correspondre à chaque construction<sup>1</sup> du subjonctif un équivalent d'où le subjonctif *en tant que forme verbale conjuguée* est absent. Évidemment ces équivalents seront parfois de style plus lourd, voire gauche, d'où l'intérêt du subjonctif. Des exemples de ce principe suivent ;

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Il ne s'agit plus de la construction en tant que schéma général d'assemblage de parties qui est discuté ci-dessus mais en tant que cas particulier de ce schéma.</sub>

> Les récoltent risquent de dépérir, *sans qu*'il *pleuvent* dès la semaine prochaine.<sup>2</sup>

- Les récoltes risquent de dépérir ***sans* de la pluie** dès la semaine prochaine.

> La direction *craint* qu'il n'y ait des **représailles**.

- Il existe dans l'état d'esprit de la direction une ***crainte* de représailles**.

> Ils *croient* qu'il y ait un **risque** et ils abandonneront.

- Il y a ***une supposition de leur part* de l'existence d'un risque** et ils abandonneront.

> Ils envisagent un régime d'égalité *afin qu*'il n'y ait plus de disputes.

- Ils envisagent un régime d'égalité  ***afin d*'en finir avec les disputes**.

<sup>2</sup><sub>Ce schéma de phrase est plus naturellement utilisée avec une inversion des propositions mais de sorte à préserver autant d'uniformité que possible la forme basée sur l'inversion n'est pas utilisée (Sans qu'il pleuve dès la semaine prochaine, les récoltes risquent de dépérir.).</sub>

On a dans « **sans** de la pluie », « **crainte de** représailles » et « **afin d**'en finir avec les disputes », des  possibilité d'action, ce qui est vrai pour l'infinitif en particulier -- le mode de l'infinitif sert à exprimer l'action en tant qu'action non réalisé -- : de la pluie, représailles, en finir avec les disputes. On voit que le mode du subjonctif est un concept qui existe **déjà** dans le groupe nominal et dans le groupe du verbe à l'infinitif, ces éléments eux-mêmes étant subordonnés au verbe d'une principale ou d'une subordonnée; ce dernier par lui-même peut suffire à constituer une phrase mais ni un groupe nominal ni un verbe à l'infinitif ne le peuvent. Le processus de mise en valeur de l'existence n'est pas une simple assertion à l'effet de dire que puisque l'on dispose des formes verbales du subjonctif alors il existe, mais une exposition du fait que c'est une chose plus profonde que ces formes, une chose dont le principe fondamental est déjà incarné dans d'autres formes du langage ; les formes dites du subjonctif ne sont que des substituts plus pratiques qui, on peut le supposer sans trop de risque, ont été greffées sur les langages en des périodes ultérieures à celles où les formes qu'elles remplacent dominaient.
Il s'ensuit,  au vu de ce raisonnement, que le concept existe (les équivalences), et que, de plus, sa systématisation  existe aussi mais cela est le sujet du « **A** » ; donc si par « structure » il est entendu « le concept »  la structure existe bien. Cependant il n'est pas approprié de parler de structure en tant que synonyme pour le nom d'un concept que l'on identifie déjà comme étant une classe, ou aspect.

Parler maintenant de la cohérence de ce concept (sur laquelle sont fondés les règles [sic]) ne convient pas;  il serait pertinent de parler de la cohérence des règles cependant; dans ce domaine aussi il n'y a pas de problème majeur et il existe un tout cohérent de règles; la grande question ou plutôt les deux grandes questions sont « Est-ce que les règles seraient relativement faciles à suivre? » et « Les règles sont-elles appliquées de façon absolument consistante dans le français écrit et parlé? »; la réponse est négative dans les deux cas.

**C** Le mot « structure » tel qu'utilisé dans la dernière phrase du corps de la question implique une contradiction du sens de structure dans la phrase précédente, où **les règles sont fondées sur la structure**; dans la troisième phrase il est question des mérites respectifs de l'utilisation de la « structure » et d'une étude du cas par cas; en tant qu'alternative du cas par cas il ne peut s'agir que des règles; donc les règles sont la structure et la structure est fondée sur la structure. Je prend le parti d'ignorer le mot « structure » dans la troisième phrase, pour n'y voir qu'une question seulement à propos de l'étude au moyen des règles et de l'étude au cas par cas. L'idée de structure a été réglée dans « **A** » et « **B** » en ce qui concerne ses premières utilisations et doit être sérieusement abandonnée dans le contexte de cette troisième phrase. L'idée de ce qui est demandé transpire suffisamment à travers les termes inadéquats pour que l'on puisse quand même répondre sans faire fausse route.

1. L'étude des règles est importante mais jusqu'à un certain point; il s'agit des règles générales comme par exemple savoir qu'avec le présent de l'indicatif dans la principale il faut le présent du subjonctif dans la subordonnée, comme savoir qu'après certains verbes l'utilisation est une question de jugement que le locuteur peut porter sur le contexte (sans chercher à mémoriser la liste de tous les verbes concernés).
2. Dans l'assimilation du subjonctif ce qui compte beaucoup c'est de savoir quels sont les verbes et locutions conjonctives après lesquels l'utiliser; on trouve des listes des verbes les plus typiques et des locutions, comme dans la référence donnée ci-dessus (BDL); il y a des indications pour chacune des locutions; cependant il est très peu productif de faire de ces listes une étude systématique : il faut les consulter pour vérifier ce qu'elles contiennent et lorsqu'on lit ou qu'on écrit pour les vérifications usuelles, et à l'occasion il est bon de les consulter pour se faire une idée du progrès que l'on aura pu faire. Le **seul moyen efficace** de maitriser ce qui est utile dans ces listes, c'est à dire d'apprendre quels sont ces verbes et locutions, c'est de lire et de parler et si possible d'écrire; lire est toujours une meilleure solution, qui permet une exploration en profondeur du langage. À force de lecture, l'utilisation du subjonctif devient une seconde nature.